# ASP.NET My country dropdownlist get bigger

Tags: asp.net, html, css, drop-down-menu

I put this code in my Load method:

```
        if (!IsPostBack)
        {
            RegionInfo reginfo;                  

            CultureInfo[] cultInfoList = CultureInfo.GetCultures(CultureTypes.AllCultures);

            foreach (CultureInfo cultInfo in cultInfoList)
            {
                try
                {

                    reginfo = new RegionInfo(cultInfo.LCID);               

                    ListItem li = new ListItem(reginfo.DisplayName, reginfo.TwoLetterISORegionName);

                    if (DropDownList2.Items.IndexOf(li) < 1)
                    { DropDownList2.Items.Add(li); }
                }
                catch 
                {

                }
            }
        }
```

but my DropDownList control changes size dramatically as loading a country with a long name, Some ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could just add a "max-width" CSS style to the ListBox.  That would be **style="max-width: 100px;"** or whatever.

Comment: I just do it, but the height of the control get bigger.

Comment: "style="max-width: 100px; max-height: 100px;" It is ok. The problem was solved. Thanks.